# Windows Java command line to know the memory settings

Tags: java

I'm looking for a windows command line that would tell me at how much the memory settings have been set to start an application.

What is the default for Windows 7 JRE 1.6 if I do "java -jar my.jar" ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Sun's JVM, `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` will print out all JVM settings:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal ...
```

The maximum heap size is shown as `MaxHeapSize`:

```
uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 1073741824      {product}
```

The value is in bytes, so in the above example it's 1GB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jinfo` (which is part of the JDK) to show the environment with which the JVM was started. If any non-standard settings were specified, it will also show them:

```
Attaching to process ID 2520, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Client compiler detected.
JVM version is 23.3-b01

Java System Properties:

java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.vm.version = 23.3-b01
...
java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.runtime.version = 1.7.0_07-b10
java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
os.arch = x86

java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
...
java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version = 51.0
sun.management.compiler = HotSpot Client Compiler
user.timezone = Europe/Berlin
java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
java.vm.info = mixed mode, sharing
java.version = 1.7.0_07

...

VM Flags:

-Xmx512m
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't have the JVM installed.

Comment: @PatB: if you don't have a JVM installed you cannot run a Java program. Do you mean by change "JDK" instead of "JVM"?

Comment: We only have a JRE sorry for the typo! I meant to write JDK not JVM :)